# How do i reskin of webkit based hone app? its got loads of css references etc and multiple js and html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, webkit

I've been put into a bind by a developer I have used, I need to reskin an open-source app from GitHub to mock up our official app.

Does it look like it's developed in vue.js / WebKit / plus a plethora of other utilities?

I have already tried to manually edit the footer and the buttons in the said footer are all misaligned and I've adjusted flex and grid etc to no avail.....

I have also tried to bring each page into say inspect and even code pen but unfortunately, I think it relies on the "tree ?" of files... I'm pretty stumped with this one... any help would be appreciated, anyway this is the link to GitHub.

https://github.com/EspressifApp/EspMeshForiOS

The developer apparently used webstorm.

Kind regards,

Chris.

Comment: has anyone seen this ?